# When I said "I like what you dislike", why was the listener confused?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

A friend of mine told me that he always dislikes K country's food, and I said,

> "I like what you dislike"

But I could see that he was so confused and was thinking what I meant, so I explained to him, "I don't like K country's food either. Then we both laughed.

I think the sentence, "I like what you dislike" can refer to
**(1), I like the thing you dislike

(2), I like the action that you have done**

He was not sure whether I was talking about (1) or (2), so he was confused.

Am I right?

Comment: Now, I am confused.  I would have thought that you meant that you like the food. If you meant the second, I would have said "I like it that you dislike it, too!"

Comment: Regarding *food* (thing), I'd use the first choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The other person may be confused on if you're talking about if you like whatever he dislikes **in general**, or if you like the thing he dislikes that he **is talking about right now**.

> X likes what Y dislikes

is parsed like this:

> X likes [what Y dislikes].

It can never mean

> I like the action that you have done.

and always means

> I like the thing you dislike

For

> I like the action that you have done

I would say any of the following:

> Me too.
>
> Same.
>
> I dislike K's food too.
>
> I dislike K's food as well.
>
> I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in your thinking.

> I **like** what you **dislike**

Means, **whatever** your friend **dislikes**, you **like**, you are being **contrarian** to him.

> I **dislike** what you **dislike**

Means you **both** dislike *something*

> I **like** **that** you **dislike**
>   I **like** your **dislike**

Means you **like** he has a certain **negative feeling** about *something*, whether or not you also like it

> I **like** that you **dislike** chocolate, it means more chocolate for me!

You could easily have said

> I **agree**!

and he would not have been confused.